# Open a port on Google vm instance

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm running a node app on a Google vm (ubuntu 16.0) instance at port 8080. I have allowed port 8080 from ufw  as well as from cloud console still I'm not able to access that port through my external ip (even after disabling ufw). Access to port like 80, 443 is working fine by allowing through ufw or disabling it.
[Cloud console firewall rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPvxc.png)

Comment: Are you going to http://...:8080 or https://...:8080?

Comment: Last Ubuntu distros come with sshguard preinstalled, so make sure that your IP is whitelisted within sshguard inside the Ubuntu instance.

Check this link for more info: https://www.sshguard.net/docs/whitelist

Answer (score 0):

port 8080 is for Jenkins  you should give this port on jenkins config file and restart the jenkins and http service to open the 8080 port using ip